# Проблема с временем работы кода

Tags: python, оптимизация, олимпиада

Есть одна олимпиада на codeforces, но не в том дело. Так вот, одно из заданий (есть во вложениях) требует найти количество пар чисел из массива длины n, сумма которых делится на k. Простой перебор всех возможных вариантов не помогает, так как стоит ограничение времени в 2 секунды. Прошу натолкнуть на мысль, как это сделать быстрее
Вот мой текущий код:

```py
#Вводим числа

#n - количество мешков
#k - количество почтальонов
#arr - массив количества писем в мешках
#complects - ответ, количество комплектов, которые можно раздать

n, k = map(int, input().split())
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
complects = 0




for i in range(0, len(arr)):   #Начинаем перебор
    if i >= len(arr):    #Если мы уже превысили длину массива, вернемся к началу
        i = 0


    for j in range(0, len(arr)):

        if j >= len(arr):  #Если мы уже превысили длину массива, вернемся к началу
            j = 0

        if len(arr) <= 1:  #Если массив состоит из 0 или 1 элементов, выходим
            break

        if i != j:  #Если мы не сравниваем одни и те же мешки


            if (arr[i] + arr[j]) % k == 0:  #Если сумма текущих 2 элементов делится на кол-во почтальонов

                complects += 1 #Прибавляем комплект и удаляем эти элементы из массива
                del1 = arr[i]
                del2 = arr[j]



                arr.remove(del1)
                arr.remove(del2)


    if len(arr) <= 1:  #Если массив состоит из 0 или 1 элементов, выходим
        break



print(complects*2)
```

> Пы.Сы. 1 раз тут, не кидайтесь тапками и прочими овощами

[image: Задание]

Comment: Я бы завел _k_ корзин, в каждую из которых сложил те числа из массива, которые дают остаток от деления на _k_ равный номеру корзины. А дальше берем любую корзину и к ней в пару берем такую, что бы сумма их номеров (остатков от деления) была равна _k_. Ну и тупо совмещаем любой мешок из первой с мешком из второй